# What is the error in sqlite query while referencing a column in a table that is a record in a column in another table

Tags: sqlite

Sqlite query

```
Select n."I_NAME" as I2Name from (select I2table from All_I) n
```

Error:

> no such column: n.I_NAME

It's checking for column n.I_NAME as against just I_NAME, n is a table alias

when I try to hardcode I2table value, no such error

Example:

```
Select n."I_NAME" as I2Name from R1I2 n
```

R1I2 is a table which has column I_NAME and I2table which is a column in All_I has a record as R1I2.

So it's about finding a column in a table which is a record in a column of another table.

How can I modify the highlighted query above?

Comment: Do you mean that `(select I2table from All_I)` returns `R1I2` and you're trying to make a dynamic query where the table name changes based on the other query?

Comment: Yes, and R1I2 is assigned to n,. R1I2 table has column I_NAME

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery `select I2table from All_I` will return table `n` with the only column `I2table`.

Next, you are querying column `n."I_NAME"` which is not in `n` table as we can see.

So, to run query without error you need to add `I_NAME` column to table `n`. The most simple way is add `as I_NAME` to subquery:

```
Select n."I_NAME" as I2Name from (select I2table as I_NAME from All_I) n
```

It's not clear what you exactly need to achieve but above query could be simplified to get the same result as follows:

```
Select n.I2table as I2Name from (select I2table from All_I) n
```

Comment: R1I2 is a record in I2Table and R1I2 has a column I_NAME.  So I2Table itself can't be considered as I_NAME

Comment: Do you mean that `select I2table from All_I` will select a table from table? `SELECT` statement must contain list of columns. Also could you clarify "R1I2 is a record in I2Table and R1I2 has a column I_NAME"? Is `R1I2` is table, column, variable or something else? How do you give a name to particular record in a table?

Comment: At least based on my comment, I assume this is supposed to be a query that dynamically selects the table from which to select the data from.

Comment: @Serg - yes, I2TABLE is a column in All_I but the values in I2Table are actually table names which R1I2 in this case.  R1I2 is a table which has a column I_Name, so it's like selecting a table from a table and then fetching it's column

Comment: @JamesZ - yes, so it's like selecting a table from a table and then fetching it's column.  All_I is a main table which has records of multiple table names under column I2Table and 1 such name is R1I2. R1I2 then has a column called I_NAME